# "How to run a single command as a background process using su -c

Tags: bash, shell, unix, adb

Running by hand,

```
adb shell
su
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &
```

Performs as expected.

However, trying to run this from a bash script using the following command does not work as expected.

```
adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &'"
```

It works without &, but with & it just won't start the binary. **exec app_process has to be a background process.**

It's possible that the shell executes the binary but then just dies, because it does not wait on anything else, but I don't know how to fix it. Making su a background process should do it, '&" but it didn't work.

When running without &, we get:

```
D/su ( 1728): 0 /system/bin/sh executing 0 
D/su ( 1728): chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
D/su ( 1728): && export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
D/su ( 1728): && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
D/su ( 1728): && exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf using shell /system/bin/sh : sh
```

When adding &, we get:

```
D/su ( 1746): 0 /system/bin/sh executing 0 
D/su ( 1746): chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
D/su ( 1746): && export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
D/su ( 1746): && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
D/su ( 1746): && exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf & using shell /system/bin/sh : sh
```

but nothing gets loaded!

How can I run my set of commands, ensuring that app_process will run in the background?

Comment: do a test with a much simpiler program to run in the background, say `sleep 30`? Then if no problem, it is something about your app_process. You say 'nothing gets loaded', but can you tell if the app_process ever gets started, is it still running? Is it hanging? (possibly waiting for input?) Look with `ps -ef | grep app_process`. Good luck.

Comment: It's not the app itself. You can tell that when it gets loaded, with:
"`D/dalvikvm( 1666): DexOpt: load 2593ms, verify 205ms, opt 22ms
...
D/dalvikvm( 1659): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/libhostConnection.so 0x40020b78, skipping init`", 
This does not happen when using &.
It has a while (true) so it would be running permanently and does not show up in the ps.
It looks like it does not get even started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have `adb` (its an old debugger right) but a good syntax for passing a set of commands to the `su` command is:

```
su -c bash <<END_BASH
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &
END_BASH
```

Comment: `adb` stands for [Android Debugger Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) and not advanced debugger which you think! Just fyi :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old question, I'd like to just document what worked for me for a specific command, `sleep 30` as suggested in a comment by shellter:

```
adb shell "su -c 'cd /data/local/tmp && nohup sleep 30 > /dev/null &'"
```

The `cd /data/local/tmp` part is necessary because nohup complains that `/` is not writeable.
The redirection to `dev/null` is necessary to avoid bloating of the `nohup` file created by `nohup` (since you want to detach, you don't really care about stdout). I know that `sleep` doesn't output anything, but that is done with a command that does output to stdout in mind.

After running this, if you do `ps -ef | grep sleep` you'll see two processes running, one of them is `sush -c cd /data/local/tmp && nohup sleep 30 > /dev/null &`. You can safely kill it through adb and only `sleep 30` will remain.

You can replace `sleep 30` with any other command. I guess you could run your bash script instead.